# Jupyter: Why does this second command stop the first one from working?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, fast-ai

I am in a Jupyter Notebook. I use these libraries:

```
from fastai.tabular import add_datepart
import pandas as pd
```

`df_raw` is a pd dataframe.

I face this really weird issue where this first command will stop working when I use this second one and then rerun the cell with the first command:

First:

```
>>> add_datepart(df_raw, 'saledate')
```

Second:

```
>>> df_raw.saleYear.head()
```

this is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'saledate'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-6b52dab581de> in <module>()
----> 1 add_datepart(df_raw, 'saledate')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/tabular/transform.py in add_datepart(df, field_name, prefix, drop, time)
     55 def add_datepart(df:DataFrame, field_name:str, prefix:str=None, drop:bool=True, time:bool=False):
     56     "Helper function that adds columns relevant to a date in the column `field_name` of `df`."
---> 57     make_date(df, field_name)
     58     field = df[field_name]
     59     prefix = ifnone(prefix, re.sub('[Dd]ate$', '', field_name))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/tabular/transform.py in make_date(df, date_field)
     10 def make_date(df:DataFrame, date_field:str):
     11     "Make sure `df[field_name]` is of the right date type."
---> 12     field_dtype = df[date_field].dtype
     13     if isinstance(field_dtype, pd.core.dtypes.dtypes.DatetimeTZDtype):
     14         field_dtype = np.datetime64

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'saledate'
```

I have never had a problem like this and do not know if pandas, fastai or jupyter is causing it. Can you help?

edit: I am not even sure if it just happens using both commands together. Right now I got the error without the second command... When I run all cells together it will compile, but as soon as I rerun the one with the "first" command this one crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [docs](https://docs.fast.ai/tabular.transform.html#add_datepart), it looks like by default the add_datepart function drops the input column from the original DataFrame. Seems a little sloppy for that to happen silently, but apparently you can disable that behavior by passing `drop=False`.

So your call would be

```py
add_datepart(df_raw, 'saledate', drop=False)
```

Comment: Oh, right. So since I dropped this feature when I first ran that command it will not find the feature when I run it a second time? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep, exactly. Most functions that work with DataFrames don't modify the original object – they return a modified copy. But you never know if third-party libraries play by the rules, and it looks like this one doesn't.